Cross-compile and run aac-fdk on Cortext M0+ like the RP2040
I am creating a small device that should be able to input sound from a I2S microphone and to compress this sound using AAC LC compression. In another thread I was recommended a Arm Cortex M for this task and I am now trying my luck with an M0, which has a decent amount of RAM, The Raspberry RP2040.
I am trying to compile and run the AAC-FDK lib on a RP2040 (Arm Cortex M0+).
So far I did setup the pico sdk and I can compile code for it.
I have also downloaded AAC-FDK from https://sourceforge.net/p/opencore-amr and tried to cross-compile it. To do this I added the following to CMakeLists.txt
include(pico_sdk_import.cmake)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -O0")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O0")

I also added
pico_sdk_init()

When I try to run cmake and make I get the following error "Error: selected processor does not support `smull r8,r2,r2,r6' in Thumb mode":
jens-imac:build deadlock$ cmake ..
PICO_SDK_PATH is /Users/deadlock/pico-sdk
PICO platform is rp2040.
Build type is Debug
Using regular optimized debug build (set PICO_DEOPTIMIZED_DEBUG=1 to de-optimize)
PICO target board is pico.
Using board configuration from /Users/deadlock/pico-sdk/src/boards/include/boards/pico.h
TinyUSB available at /Users/deadlock/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/portable/raspberrypi/rp2040; enabling build support for USB.
Compiling TinyUSB with CFG_TUSB_DEBUG=1
BTstack available at /Users/deadlock/pico-sdk/lib/btstack
cyw43-driver available at /Users/deadlock/pico-sdk/lib/cyw43-driver
Pico W Bluetooth build support available.
lwIP available at /Users/deadlock/pico-sdk/lib/lwip
mbedtls available at /Users/deadlock/pico-sdk/lib/mbedtls
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/deadlock/opencore-amr-fdk-aac/build
jens-imac:build deadlock$ make
[  1%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fdk-aac.dir/libAACdec/src/FDK_delay.cpp.obj
[  1%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fdk-aac.dir/libAACdec/src/aac_ram.cpp.obj
[  2%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fdk-aac.dir/libAACdec/src/aac_rom.cpp.obj
[  2%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fdk-aac.dir/libAACdec/src/aacdec_drc.cpp.obj
/var/folders/5_/9gsrt3xn33943bbcn4433d5m0000gn/T//cc2jypDI.s: Assembler messages:
/var/folders/5_/9gsrt3xn33943bbcn4433d5m0000gn/T//cc2jypDI.s:2032: Error: selected processor does not support `smlal r5,r0,r2,r3' in Thumb mode
/var/folders/5_/9gsrt3xn33943bbcn4433d5m0000gn/T//cc2jypDI.s:2063: Error: selected processor does not support `smull r2,r3,r3,r1' in Thumb mode
/var/folders/5_/9gsrt3xn33943bbcn4433d5m0000gn/T//cc2jypDI.s:2111: Error: selected processor does not support `smlal r3,r4,r0,r2' in Thumb mode
/var/folders/5_/9gsrt3xn33943bbcn4433d5m0000gn/T//cc2jypDI.s:4336: Error: selected processor does not support `smull ip,r3,r3,r0' in Thumb mode
/var/folders/5_/9gsrt3xn33943bbcn4433d5m0000gn/T//cc2jypDI.s:4400: Error: selected processor does not support `smull ip,r0,r0,r1' in Thumb mode
/var/folders/5_/9gsrt3xn33943bbcn4433d5m0000gn/T//cc2jypDI.s:4467: Error: selected processor does not support `smull r0,r3,r3,ip' in Thumb mode
/var/folders/5_/9gsrt3xn33943bbcn4433d5m0000gn/T//cc2jypDI.s:4909: Error: selected processor does not support `smull r0,r3,r3,r1' in Thumb mode
/var/folders/5_/9gsrt3xn33943bbcn4433d5m0000gn/T//cc2jypDI.s:5678: Error: selected processor does not support `smull r8,r3,r3,r7' in Thumb mode
/var/folders/5_/9gsrt3xn33943bbcn4433d5m0000gn/T//cc2jypDI.s:5905: Error: selected processor does not support `smull r2,r1,r3,r9' in Thumb mode
/var/folders/5_/9gsrt3xn33943bbcn4433d5m0000gn/T//cc2jypDI.s:5944: Error: selected processor does not support `smull r0,r2,r2,r4' in Thumb mode
/var/folders/5_/9gsrt3xn33943bbcn4433d5m0000gn/T//cc2jypDI.s:5986: Error: selected processor does not support `smull r2,r3,r3,r6' in Thumb mode
/var/folders/5_/9gsrt3xn33943bbcn4433d5m0000gn/T//cc2jypDI.s:6166: Error: selected processor does not support `smull r8,r2,r2,r6' in Thumb mode
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/fdk-aac.dir/libAACdec/src/aacdec_drc.cpp.obj] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/fdk-aac.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

I managed to overcome this issue by rm -rf * in the build folder and cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF ..
Now I get some warnings such as rdhi, rdlo and rm must all be different however when googling the error it can be safely ignored on newer ARM architectures which I assume the RP2040 is.
Anyway now I have a libfdk-aac.a which is around 8MB in size.
In my main pico project I add it to the CMakeLists.txt like this:
target_link_libraries(PicoTest pico_stdlib pico_audio pico_audio_i2s "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../opencore-amr-fdk-aac/build/libfdk-aac.a")

target_include_directories (PicoTest PUBLIC "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/includes")

I can now include files and reference structures and functions from the library. So i:
#include "aacenc_lib.h"

and in my main() function I try to call the simplest possible function
LIB_INFO info;
aacEncGetLibInfo(&info);

And at the aacEncGetLibInfo row the processor just hangs. There is no execution after this point.
My main belief is that there is some kind of inconsistancy between the library I built and my main code. But both are using the pico sdk and I have no idea on how to troubleshoot this. Any suggestions are welcome.

Technically, how to compile that pure software library to run on a RP2040 is not really an electrical engineering problem. Have you asked on the support forums of that library how to build it for your CPU, or if it is even a supported CPU?

`smull r8,r2,r2,r6 is a 32 bit regular ARM instruction, but you're compiling for a thumb2 CPU that doesn't support regular ARM, so something is wrong with your build flags. Probably you are defining ARMv5/6 and including the wrong inline assembly instructions.
